# Intermitent Hyper-V Cluster Network connectivity loss - Server 2012 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, windows-cluster, packetloss, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am running a 3 node Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Hyper-V cluster on three DL560s together with a HP P2000 SAN (FC) and HP 1810-24G v2 Switches.

I have been experiencing intermittent network connectivity loss on all of the guest VMs on a particular host node. The cluster networks all report as up as well as the guest network on both the physical host and the affected guest VMs, but you cannot ping all the guest VMs on the affected host node.

I have tried to live migrate the affected VMs over to the other hosts but as soon as they complete within a few minutes all physical hosts loss connectivity.

The only solution I've found that works so far is to unplug the physical network cable and plug it back in again.

I would appreciate any light with regards to the above. I have tried updating the network card drivers, windows updates and disabling network optimizations on the VMs and physical NIC.

Any help or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question. Each port on the switch which is directly connected to a virtual switch on the VM hosts was configured as a trunk instead of a normal switch port. It seems that physical NICs attached to a virtual network are configured as trunks by default, the link below refers:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1306.hyper-v-configure-vlans-and-vlan-tagging.aspx

So far no incidents.

Hope this helps anyone.